# Spek unexpected order execution

Tags: unit-testing, testing, kotlin, spek

how can I execute `val chromeDriver = setupChromeDriverForTest()` only once? I was expected that it happens if I put it in before given section, but It is called twice (with single test as you see). So I get an exception (File is using by another process), because the `setupChromeDriverForTest()` method loads File.

```
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform::class)
class ChromeDriverConfigurationTest : Spek
({
    val chromeDriver = setupChromeDriverForTest()
    given("chrome_driver") {
        on("fetching js text") {
            val path = ChromeDriverConfigurationTest::class.java.getResource("js/js.html").path
            val text = fetchTextAndDeleteDriver(chromeDriver, path)
            it("should find text") {
                assert(text == "Text from JS!")
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: val chromeDriver: `your_type` by lazy { setupChromeDriverForTest }

Comment: great it works! :D